# Do virtual machine snapshots shorten the life of SSDs?

Tags: virtualbox, ssd, virtual-machine, nvme

A long while ago, I read that HDDs should be preferred over SSDs for virtual machine workloads because frequent snapshot creation and deletion would shorten the life of the SSD.  I'm a developer and I use virtual machines heavily for development and testing.  I frequently use snapshotting to test different configurations and to roll back things like bad updates.  At the time I was getting a new computer so I opted to get two drives: an SSD for the OS and home partitions and an HDD for the VMs.  Over the years, I've sort of read articles from time to time like [this one](https://www.extremetech.com/computing/206638-researchers-ssds-struggle-in-virtual-machines-thanks-to-garbage-collection) that seem to indicate that the older advice might still be the case.  But it's been a long time since I've dived in and really tried to find solid evidence-based tests or information.

Fast forward to now and I'm looking to buy a laptop and it seems getting an HDD is a very rare option.  Most of the available drives are NVMe SSDs.  I've been searching all over, including on here and ServerFault, for any information but I can't seem to find any info indicating one way or another whether advances in SSD tech have made that old guidance obsolete or not.  I've found several places saying that it's fine to put VMs on SSDs but none of them really say anything about using snapshotting frequently so I'm hoping someone with experience in this area could chime in with some info or experience.

Does frequent use of VM snapshots significantly decrease the life of SSDs?  I'm assuming that consumer grade NVMe drives might not be up to the task so should I look at getting an enterprise grade NVMe drive for the VM partition?  If so, any recommendations on what search terms to use when looking for a drive for this particular type of workload?

Comment: “I'm assuming that consumer grade NVMe drives might not be up to the task so should I look at getting an enterprise grade NVMe drive for the VM partition?” - Most consumer SSDs brands actually have several Petabytes lifespan.

Answer (score 0):

No. Not in any appreciable sense,

A good quality SSD has a long life - normally longer than the computer it is in.

I have a ThinkPad X1 from 2016 that ran VMware Workstation on Windows 10 and I shrunk VMs weekly. It is still running fine.

I have  a ThinkPad X1 from 2022 running VMware Workstation on Windows 11 and I shrink VMs weekly. It also is running fine.

TRIM makes sure usage is evened out and a good SSD should not have any issues.

My drives have a capacity of 600 TB written.